# Should pregnancy wait?

Tags: food, reproduction, humanoid

Robin and Lisa have run into a bit of a conundrum. They just planted a garden in the beginning of spring and are growing fruits, vegetables, and grains, some of which came from Robin's grandparents. Lisa wants to become pregnant right away. Robin is cautious and wants to wait a year before they have a baby. They have already received their knitting kit and interplanetary communicator. And Robin has dug a tunnel connecting their home to that of his grandparents.

Given that they have a 20 month year, they should have plenty of time for a bountiful harvest. But my question is whether or not pregnancy should be put off for a year.

If Lisa gets pregnant right away, there is a higher risk that she will either miscarry, give birth prematurely, or have a stillbirth, especially since she doesn't have much in terms of fat reserves but plenty of muscle. There is also a higher risk that the baby will starve to death despite frequent nursing.

If she waits for a year, these risks are a lot lower. But she will get impatient long before that 1 year mark.

**So should she wait to become pregnant or take the risks and become pregnant before a bountiful harvest?**

Comment: If the mating is like us (several times a year) and you don't wind up with postpartum depression than do both. How manual is the harvest? How robust is the species re birth? Many earth species and quite few societies birth is nothing terrible. Or have them lay eggs. Eggs are much simpler. ;-)

Comment: This question is unclear: 1 year is 20 months long. But how long is a month with respect to earth? How long does the pregnancy last? How is the development of the newborn (human like with extensive care, or cow like with early independence?) Is the only concern a grumpy wife?

Comment: The risks of a pregnancy now may be offset by her nutritional intake. Presumably, muscular women with low fat reserves can give birth to healthy, full-term babies. So the question should be, is she eating well right now and enough for a healthy pregnancy.

Comment: The length of the seasonal cycle and local climate is more important than the length of the year. Some regions get two growing seasons, some one, some can grow crops all year. You have a random note about an interplanetary communicator, does that mean they're using intensive modern methods or are they just putting seeds in the ground and hoping?

Comment: 'Robin has dug a tunnel connecting their home to that of his grandparents' - that is a little unusual. I think there is a lot of background information missing here.

Comment: I feel that this is asking about the choices of individual characters, which is not about worldbuilding. Can you clarify how this question is about *building a world* as opposed to *what a specific character would or should do*?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, she should wait. The only argument against that seems to be her impatience. Getting pregnant right away is not only high-risk, but she will be depriving her family of her assistance when they are most likely to need it, as well as possibly reducing the effectiveness of their labour during that first year because of her needs and the needs of her unborn child, and then subsequently of her young baby.

Any other decision just makes her look selfish, inconsiderate, and reckless.